# Looping over the array of other function in current function

Tags: python

I need a help to know how can I can iterate a loop over a array which is in another function of the same class.

I tried using the following similar code for automation in selenium and I get the following error.

```
class Test:
    def array_method1(self, product):
        self.product = product
        if product == "First":
           group1 = ['A','B','C']
        elif product == "Second":
           group2 = ['C','D','E']

     def iterate_product(self, product):
        self.product = product
        for test in self.array_method1(product):
            browser.find_element_by_name(test).click()
```

I called the function as `iterate_product('First')` and I got the error as:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: I found the problem why I was getting the error, it was due to the wrong  parameters I was sending to the  function in my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code `array_method1` above does not return anything hence it returns `None` so you can not iterate through it with the line:

```
for test in self.array_method1(product):
```

`array_method1` needs to return like:

```
    self.product = product
    if product == "First":
       result = ['A','B','C']
    elif product == "Second":
       result = ['C','D','E']
    else:
       result = []
    return result
```